# RTL passwords copy/ pasting issue

Tags: javascript, php, passwords, right-to-left, left-to-right

I'm developing a portal in RTL language with a password generator in php/ javascript that generates randomly passwords like

```
F1O=a@9@
```

or

```
7$kf8F=og!$
```

However if i paste such passwords with special chars into the RTL field they are completly wrong.

A fiddle of the issue can be found [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/7tqdmcLs/1/).

How to overcome such an issue?
Excluding special chars in passwords is not an option as it would decrease security.

Thanks for any hint in advance.

Comment: Is this really "php" related? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how it works, if you simply want text on the right, use css instead.

```html
<style>
  input[type="text"] {
    text-align: right
  }
</style>

<label>RTL FIELD</label>
<input type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Seems to work for now, thanks. Need to test it once the site is live.